# Setting SessionScope on XPage open

Tags: view, xpages, session-scope

I have an Xpage with a view within it that displays search results that are based on the values of 6 fields on the xpage (These values are assigned to sessionscope variables when they selected, which drives the view selection when the search button is hit).  This all works well, but what I'd like to change is that the view is empty when the xpage is opened initially (before any values are set).

Apologies for the simple question, but I haven't touched notes since 2006 and its changed a fair bit since then.

Running 8.5.2.

Comment: Please try to be more specific regarding the kind of search (full text? key value?). Also show some example code especially regarding the search filter

Comment: Hi, I have been following this example (http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/XPagesViewControlAddFullTextSearch.htm), so a full Text Search.  I'm actually wondering if I'm asking the wrong question.  Is there a way to set sessionscop (or view scope thanks Knut) as you open an xpage (regardless of what you're doing once you're in the page?).  I will post the code soon if you think thats still required (I don't have it on hand at the moment).  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **viewScope** instead sessionScope.

**viewScope** variables exist for the duration of the current XPage in current browser tab. If you open another XPage or open current XPage in another tab the values of viewScope variables are gone. That is what you need in your case.

**sessionScope** variables last for the duration of a user session in a browser across all browser tabs. That's why your current search values are set as default in another browser tab.

Answer (score 1):

Each bean is instantiated when the scope is "initiated". For sessionScope this when you first open the site. For viewScope it is when you first open the page (will survive partial refreshes). And variables in these scope are just maps (i.e. beans) in that scope.

So to set an initial value you could either use a real bean - and just add whatever code you need in its constructor.

Or, if you want to use SSJS, you can add the check when loading a page (e.g. in the beforePageLoad event). If you are working in sessionScope you should check if a value is already set - and if not --> set it. In viewScope you would just initiate the variable.

And a word on scopes. If at all possible you should always prefer the "shorter" timed scope for performance/scalability purposes. See a little more about using sessionScope in [my article about tuning XPages](http://www.dalsgaard-data.eu/blog/tuning-your-xpages/) :-)

/John